# memory limitations when processing large raster

Tags: raster, terra

I have a large raster and I do not understand how to process it. My assumption was that I can cut it into tiles, make a vrt and then process the vrt to get the answer. But it is not so (at least not using my code), so I hope to find some guidance here.

My code:

```
library(terra)

f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package = "terra")
v <- vect(f)
r <- rast(v)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
tester <- zonal(r, v, fun = "max") # this works fine

r2 <- disagg(r, fact = c(4000, 5000)) # make a really big raster
tester <- zonal(r2, v, fun = "max") # calculation that is too big to handle
# this throws Error: std::bad_alloc


filename <- "test_tile/test_.tif"
ff <- makeTiles(r2, 10000, filename) # make it into many small tiles, hopefully to process
vrtfile <- "test_tile/testing.vrt"
vrt_thing <- vrt(ff, vrtfile, overwrite=T)

tester <- zonal(vrt_thing, v, fun = "max") 
# this also throws Error:std::bad_alloc

# my options:
terraOptions()
memfrac   : 0.6
tolerance : 0.1
verbose   : FALSE
todisk    : FALSE
tempdir   : C:/Users/vic039/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp6nthBI
datatype  : FLT4S
memmin    : 1
progress  : 3
```

In a nutshell, I thought each tile would be processed in the background with that call, one at a time, and the results magically stitched together. That is not how it works, which indicates I have misunderstood something. Any help to find a way to do my zonal calculation much appreciated. (note, this is a reproducible example, not my data... I am not looking for the literal result from this file...). Ultimately I need to perform this calculation many times with many different polygons one one static raster.

I understand that changing my terraOptions might improve things, but I am unsure of which settings to alter. Any help appreciated.